# 'ConsoleApplication1.Student' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#

I am Student who is learning `c#`, when I executed the program got error.

`On console`: I am expecting to see the string `'Harry'`.

> Error: 'ConsoleApplication1.Student' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

```
  namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student("Harry");
        System.Console.WriteLine(student.ToString());
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Question:** How can I solve the program? Anyone guide me, please.

Comment: you need to write an constructor within your class: "public Student(string name) { this.Name = name; } "

Comment: No, he needs to define a constructor which takes one argument, namely the name.

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx

Comment: Yes, it's a special kind of a method.  See any of the posted answers below.

Comment: You don't need to provide a constructor, you can use object initializer: `Student student = new Student{Name="Harry"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then create a constructor that takes 1 arguments.

> On console, i am expecting to see the string 'Harry'

So, you need to add override to merthod `ToString()` like:

```
class Student
{
    public  string Name {get; set;}

    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString();
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your class need a constructor with one argument.

```
Student student = new Student("Harry");
System.Console.WriteLine(student.ToString());
```

**Class:**

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Student(string Name) //constructor here
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public override string ToString() //overload of ToString
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

---

As Tim mentionend - another way is to leave the class untouched and just set and read the property

```
Student student = new Student() { Name = "Harry" };
Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
```

**Class:**

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that he could also use object initializer: `Student student = new Student{ Name="Harry" };`

Comment: ConsoleApplication1.Student visible on console, anything wrong with my code? Let me try as per you reply.

Comment: it says ConsoleApplication1.Student doesnot contain a constructor that takes 0 argument. I tried Student student = new Student{ Name="Harry" }

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your student class to have a constructor that takes one parameter

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Student(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public Student() { }
}
```

Comment: On console, i can see ConsoleApplication1.Student only

Answer (score 0):

You did not defined any Constructor, especiall none with 1 argument, but you are trying to use such a by calling Student("Harry") :-).

Define Constructor with String argument and it will be fine.